# Java library\application to Build SQL Frontend GUI's

Tags: java, sql, swing, swt

Does anyone know of a java library or application that allows for SQL front end manipulation via java GUI's e.g. Swing or SWT?

I am looking for something similar to ASP .Net Datagrid, where you essentially 'plugin' the queries, set a few things up and voila!

I've used Spring JDBC quite a bit and have been playing with the JDBC template to try and build a generic project that does this - but still it seems like what I am doing has been done before, albeit more elegantly :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know SQuirreL?

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/